# Flutter image not showing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-assetimage

The image is not showing. While running, it shows this error but it is running without image. I have used tab between the '-' and the image path. I have also created a folder called assets and a subfolder slider_icons and included my images in it.

This is exactly how my pubspec.yaml looks like,

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
  - assets/slider_icons/burger.png
  - assets/slider_icons/pizza.png
  - assets/slider_icons/biryani.png
  - assets/slider_icons/parotta.jpeg
  - assets/slider_icons/cup.png
  - assets/slider_icons/drink.png
  - assets/slider_icons/chicken-fries.png
```

Error:-

```
[foodie] flutter pub get
```

Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 48, column 7: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
╷
48 │       assets:
│       ^
╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at F:\Learn flutter\foodie\pubspec.yaml
exit code 1

[This is the screen shot of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6p2i.png)

Comment: add code please

Comment: I added the coding now

Comment: Can you provide the error code as well?

Comment: check log,did it display any errors?

Comment: Yes it displays error...I will post the error too

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. The problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `assets:` has to go exactly under the `#` and the `-` needs two spaces. Additionally, when you use images from the same folder you can add all the images with one line as written below.

**How it should be written:**

```
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
  - assets/slider_icons/
```

Comment: if you have deleted the default comment you should just add 2 spaces from the beginning of the word, assets:

Answer (score 0):

The way to include an image inside Flutter is:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

You also have to create a directory where you can put the resource inside it.

Comment: I did this exact way...But still the image isn't showing. I have also created the folders and brought all the images into the folder